# mysql SELECT DATEDIFF from rate ranges and get price

Tags: mysql, database, datediff

Im trying to get the grand total rate If a person checks in on 2/3/22 and checks out on 2/6/2022 . Some days fall under different rate ranges, you will see below I was able to get how many days are in each range, but I need total price. any help would be great.
So for example 267+267+281 = 815

Data

| Unit | fromdate | todate | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| motel5 | 2022-01-10 | 2022-02-04 | 281 |
| motel5 | 2022-02-05 | 2022-03-04 | 267 |

Query

```
SELECT unit, fromdate, todate, day, 
(DATEDIFF( IF (todate > '2022-02-06' , '2022-02-06', todate), 
IF ( fromdate < '2022-02-02' , '2022-02-02' , fromdate )) ) 
AS days FROM rates_new WHERE fromdate <= '2022-02-06' 
AND todate > '2022-02-02' AND Unit = 'motel5'
ORDER BY days ASC
```

Result

| Unit | fromdate | todate | day | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| motel5 | 2022-01-10 | 2022-02-04 | 281 | 2 |
| motel5 | 2022-02-05 | 2022-03-25 | 267 | 1 |

Comment: Your current query will return 281 = 2 days .. and 267 = 1 day. So it's actually 281+281+267=829

Comment: *If a person checks in on 2/3/22 and checks out on 2/6/2022* the days included should be 3, 4, 5, but according to your *Result*, it looks like 4, 5, 6, do you mean to include check out date but excluding check in date, and what's the MySQL version please.

Comment: @FanoFN the qeaution is how do we get the code to give us the 829?

Comment: @ProGu Im just trying to figure out how to make this code give me total price

Comment: @LynnRoss , from your current data sample and your condition, what would be the correct result? I mention in my comment earlier that _your current query_ is returning `281+281+267=829` instead of what you claim as `267+267+281=815`. So, I'm saying that it's either your query is wrong, or your expected result is wrong. Please clarify, thanks

Comment: @FanoFN query must be wrong it should give total go 829

Comment: Your query *would* give 829...

Comment: Maybe you should define what your boundaries in the table really mean -- if a range ends at 2022-02-04 is it sill valid for the night between 2022-02-04 and 2022-02-05; if a range begins at 2022-01-10, is it already valid for the night from 2022-01-09 to 2022-01-10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can modify your query to something like this:

```
SET @mindt := '2022-02-02';
SET @maxdt := '2022-02-06';

SELECT unit,
       SUM(days*day)
       FROM
(SELECT unit, fromdate, todate, day,
        DATEDIFF(IF(todate > @maxdt, @maxdt, todate), 
                  IF(fromdate < @mindt, @mindt, fromdate)) AS days
  FROM rates_new 
  WHERE fromdate <= '2022-02-06' 
  AND todate > '2022-02-02') V
GROUP BY unit;
```

Instead of defining the date in the query, try make use of variables so you'll only need to change the date value from the variable and place the variable accordingly in your query. Then remove this condition:

```
AND Unit = 'motel5'
```

and turn the query into a subquery. From there you can just do the calculation of `SUM(days*day)` then group by `unit`.

[Updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e3bb4bb7e3333bb73a7306996a4ee1d)

Comment: @FanFN if insert the following rates and then try your code something goes wrong can you help?
('motel5', '2022-01-10', '2022-02-04', 273),
('motel5', '2022-02-05', '2022-04-01', 324),
('motel5', '2022-04-02', '2022-04-08', 310),
('motel5', '2022-04-09', '2022-04-22', 559),
('motel5', '2022-04-23', '2022-04-29', 437),
('motel5', '2022-04-30', '2022-05-06', 466),
('motel5', '2022-05-07', '2022-05-13', 557),
('motel5', '2022-05-14', '2022-05-20', 613),
('motel5', '2022-05-21', '2022-06-03', 634),
('motel5', '2022-06-04', '2022-06-10', 659),
('motel5', '2022-06-11', '2022-06-17', 717);

Comment: That depends, but if your current issue is already solved by any of the posted answer here, you should accept one answer and consider this as solved. Any follow-up issue should be posted as a separate question. I learned that ["chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are very discouraged.

Comment: I see, well, the `DATEDIFF()` part is actually the same as you original query so I just re-use it back but replaced the defined date with variables. At a glance, I can see that the condition placed in `IF()` is what makes the results wrong. Let me see what I can do

Comment: Sorry @LynnRoss , it looks like the `WHERE fromdate <= '2022-02-06' 
  AND todate > '2022-02-02'` is necessary after all. I've edited my answer with new query and fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `least()` and `greatest()` to get the effective boundary within a range between the end date of the range or of the visit. The use `datediff()` to get the difference in day, multiply with the price and aggregate using `sum()` to get the total price for the visit.

```
SELECT sum(datediff(least(adddate('2022-02-06',
                                  INTERVAL 1 DAY),
                          todate),
                    greatest('2022-02-03',
                             fromdate))
           * day)
       FROM rates_new
       WHERE unit = 'motel5'
             AND fromdate <= '2022-02-06'
             AND todate >= '2022-02-03';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8398994b9bd964746b9ef7da9e42c4bd)

Comment: the total price should be 829, not 815 wonder why its getting 815

Comment: @LynnRoss: *You* wrote 815 as the desired result!

Comment: so say we added another hotal to the ranges lets say motel 6, how could we get total for both?

Comment: @LynnRoss: For the same check in and check out? Use `unit IN ('motel5', 'motel6')` instead of `unit = 'motel5'`. But that doesn't solve the mystery a about which sum is right, 815 or 829...

Comment: if I have like 60 hotels, but don't want to define each one like unit IN ('motel5', 'motel6')  how could I do that?

Comment: @LynnRoss: Leave the condition about units completely out of the `WHERE` clause and add a `GROUP BY unit` clause. But please stop extending the original question. *This* questions seems solved, either with your query or mine. If you got a follow up question, open a new one. And this time specify everything what you actually have and want beforehand, so that you don't need to extend via comments again.